# hard/soft block by rfkill

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, 16.04

I have a trouble with my wifi hardware. It can't be unblocked by `rfkill` so I can't use it. I'm a beginer in Ubuntu and I have dual boot with Windows 10 on Acer Aspire ES1-421-88QX. 
Can you tell me how to fix it ??
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

copy and paste (line by line) the following into a terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi
cd /etc/modprobe.d
sudo nano blacklist.conf
```

Then add `blacklist acer-wmi` as a new line at the end of the file.

Save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and reboot.

Comment: i am glad it worked out for you. don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

if you have the realtek NIC then you should try this  [tape trick](https://youtu.be/yzAKcmlaH1M) only after the problem still persists after trying the other solutions such as unblock command. In my laptop the same problem had occurred and I myself applied the trick and since then my WiFi works like charm.